# Способы выборки данных из родительской таблицы и нескольких дочерних

Tags: sql

Возьмем сферический пример с тремя базами данных:

main:

```
 id | title
 ---|------
  1 | alpha
  2 | beta
  3 | gamma
```

sub1:

```
 id | id_main | sub1
 ---|---------|-------
  1 |       1 | альфа
  2 |       3 | гамма1
  3 |       3 | гамма2
```

sub2:

```
 id | id_main | sub2
 ---|---------|--------
  1 |       1 | Άλφα
  2 |       3 | Γάμμα1
  3 |       3 | Γάμμα2
```

Навскидку назову три варианта собрать все данные вместе:

- Сделать последовательно три запроса - по запросу к каждой таблице.
- Сделать запрос с LEFT/RIGHT JOIN, получив одну таблицу типа:

(result)

```
id | title  | sub1 | sub2
 ---|-------|--------|--------
  1 | alpha | альфа  | Άλφα
  2 | beta  | NULL   | NULL
  3 | gamma | гамма1 | Γάμμα1
  3 | gamma | гамма1 | Γάμμα2
  3 | gamma | гамма2 | Γάμμα1
  3 | gamma | гамма2 | Γάμμα2
```

- Сделать запрос с UNION SELECT, чтобы получить все данные в виде пар ключ/значение:

(result)

```
 id | value  | table
 ---|--------|-----
  1 | alpha  | main
  1 | альфа  | sub1
  1 | Άλφα  | sub2
  2 | beta   | main
  3 | gamma  | main
  3 | гамма1 | sub1
  3 | гамма2 | sub1
  3 | Γάμμα1 | sub2
  3 | Γάμμα2 | sub2
```

Есть ли ещё способы сделать выборку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще один сферический вариант.

```
select main.id, main.title, 
  sub1.id as sub_id, sub1.title as sub_title, 'sub1' as _table
from main
join sub1 on main.id = sub_id_main
union all
select main.id, main.title, 
  sub2.id, sub2.title, 'sub2'
from main
join sub2 on main.id = sub_id_main
```

Все зависит от того, зачем вам данные. Сферический вариант смысла рассматривать нет, нужен физический смысл.

Comment: Прикольный вариант. Запомним. Спасибо!! А сферический вариант - это для того, чтобы абстрагироваться от конкретного случая. Я понимаю, что под конкретную задачу подходит свой инструмент, и всё же хочется проверить, нет ли еще инструментов?

Comment: Ну, вы должны рассуждать какие данные вы вытаскиваете. Тут получается, что для каждой строки из main мы берем n строк из sub1 (получаем связь main и sub1) и получаем m строк из sub2 (связь main и sub2). В итоге получится m+n строк. Повторы будут только для main, т.е. по ним можно итерировать и определить к какой строке из main какое дочернее значение соответствует.  

В принципе это вариант значений многозначных свойств. У каждого юзера может быть произвольное количество, скажем, постов и произвольное количество комментариев...